# How would I change the controller for a route, by depending on a flag set within the model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I currently have a dynamic route set up:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
...
    this.resource('simpleSearch', {path: 'simplesearch'}, function () {
        this.resource('simpleSearchOption', {path: ':simpleSearchOption_id'});
...
```

I do have `simpleSearchOptionController` set up, with all of the functions and actions that I need, but there is a special case in which I require some other initialization, and extra functions, but otherwise the controller is the same, so I extended the previous one:

```
App.SimpleSearchOptionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    needs: ["simpleSearch"],
    simpleSearch: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.simpleSearch"),
    // ... Stuff used in the "subclass" as well...
    // ...
});

App.SimpleSearchWidthHeightController = App.SimpleSearchOptionController.extend({

    init: function () {
        this._super();
        //... More stuff than the original controller
    },
    // More functions and so forth that are needed in this case, but not in the "super class'"
    //...
});
```

Here is my route:

```
App.SimpleSearchOptionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
    model: function (params) {
        return this.modelFor('simpleSearch').get('simpleSearchOptions')[params.simpleSearchOption_id];
    },

    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
        this.controllerFor('simpleSearch').set('currentQuestion', controller.get('id'));
    }
});
```

[I see that I can set the `controllerName`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controllerName) in the route.

Is there a way that I can change the `controllerName` *after* the route obtains the model object, but *before* it chooses and instantiates the controller, so I can choose the controller based on a flag set in the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `renderTemplate` hook in the route.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
  var controllerName = 'foo';
  if(model.get('something') === 'bar'){
    controllerName = 'bar';
  }
  this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
    controller: controllerName        // the controller to use for the template
  });
}
```

Now, you may need to grab the controller and initalize it since you have a model, it'd be like this

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {

  if(model.get('something') === 'bar'){
    controller = this.controllerFor('bar');
    controller.set('model', model);
    // other random stuff you may be doing in setupController
  }
  this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
    controller: controller        // the controller to use for the template
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, alright.  This works well, thank you!  I commented out `setupController` in the Route.  Does that mean that `renderTemplate` replaces `setupController` when using it in this fashion?  I skimmed right over that in the guide because I figured the controller serves a separate purpose from the view, and so would be handled separately, something like a `renderTemplate` function, but along the lines of `instantiateController` instead.  Thanks again!

Comment: using it in this fashion does indeed render `setupController` pointless.